# What should I do with an open question that is no longer relevant to me?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432599/wpf-selected-item-of-gridview-on-hyperlink-click) question and received what I believe to be a very good answer that just didn't quite work for my situation, for reasons I've not had time to figure out. Due to a change in requirements, this question is no longer relevant to me and I will likely never be able to accept an answer... even if someone puts in the time to come up with the correct solution. I just can't replicate it anymore.

So my question is, what should I do with it? Should I..

a) Delete the question

b) Leave it as is, unanswered

c) Accept what I believe to be a good answer that may help others with a similar issue, even though it's not the exact answer to my question

One reason I ask is because I don't want someone to put in the time and effort to come up with a great solution knowing I will likely never be able to confirm or accept an answer.

Comment: Your second sentence makes a nice comment, which I, as an answerer, would be perfectly satisfied with.

Comment: title: irrelevant to you =/= irrelevant to the community. (a) You can't. (b) it has an answer (c) if it doesn't answer your question then the answer or the question needs improvement.

Comment: @Jordy I think you misunderstand, by unanswered I'm talking about an accepted answer. Also I can't really improve the question as I can no longer replicate the issue, which is why I'm asking what to do with it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks, so just add a disclaimer basically? That makes sense

Comment: duplicate of my own question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112967/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Whether you accept the answer is entirely [up to you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
>   statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that
>   worked for him or her personally, but not every user comes back to
>   accept an answer, and of those who do, they may not change the
>   accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later.

That said, do **not** delete the question. Just because the question is no longer relevant to you doesn't mean that it won't be relevant to some Internet wanderer in the future. Even if you don't accept the answer, it will still be there for others to read if they find your question and are experiencing the same (or a similar) issue.

If it doesn't work for you, but you feel that it is *useful*, upvote it to indicate that it is a correct answer to your *question*, even if it no longer applies to your personal issue.

I believe that the best option here would be to upvote it and, as Jörg W Mittag suggested, leave it unanswered with a comment or edit to the question:

> Due to a change in requirements, this question is no longer relevant to me and I will likely never be able to accept an answer. Even if someone puts in the time to come up with the correct solution, I won't be able to verify its correctness.

Comment: Actually, there is a case for this. The close reason off-topic: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. ". If he adds that blurb and people vote to close for off-topic, it would be appropriate and no more answers could be added. He could even flag it to be closed for that reason.

Comment: @staticx That's true. I'm not a C# guy, so I can't tell you whether it was a minor error or something more; if it's the former case, then obviously it should be closed, but, from the tone of the post, I assumed it was simply something that *no longer applied to the OP* but was still an error that others could come across.

Comment: Sounds to me like can no longer be produced still

Comment: @staticx I'm not so sure: the OP said that the `requirements changed`, not that the issue can't be reproduced.

Comment: I'd say accept the answer, but leave that last comment, modified appropriately: "... no longer relevant to me and I will likely never be able to verify that this answer works."

Comment: @Teepeemm I like that ending better since it fits the situation; I've updated the answer with it.

Comment: @AstroCB To clarify, you are correct. The requirements changed and I no longer have access to the code in question. If it was the case of a simple mistake then I don't know it yet so I have to assume it could still be relevant to others :)

Answer (score 15):

Here's another option: answer your own question! If the question isn't relevant any more or you found the answer, give an explanation. You probably learned quite a bit talking with others, reading responses, or researching further. Compile all that information into a concise package for others to read. If you can explain what happened, what information you found, or why the existing answers didn't quite fit the bill, you're providing even more information to future readers.

It might not be meaningful to you any more, but it sure might help out the next guy.

Answer (score -1):

I was in a similar situation, and was able to ask another user to confirm whether an answer resolved the problem, and I accepted the answer on that basis.

So leave the question open, and if an opportunity to confirm a solution arises, take it. (You could add a request for such assistance in the question.)